# Creating an Index of Locations with Biblatex and Imakeidx

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, indexing, imakeidx

I would like to send the "address" field of my bibliography into an index (not the default one)
My code is not working:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}

@book{Dol2,
    Address = {Moskwa},
    Author = {Philip Döllinger},
    Publisher = {Sinodal'naja tip.},
    Title = {Sistematičeskoe opisanie rukopisej moskovskoj Sinodal'noj (patriaršej) biblioteki},
    Year = {1894}}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[A4, 11pt, twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                        % Per le sillabazioni
    \setmainlanguage{italian}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COMANDI DI BILIOGRAFIA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,indexing=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{archivio.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%INDICI%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=luoghi, title=Luoghi]


\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{address}{%
\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index[luoghi]}{%
       \thefield{address}\subentryoperator%
       \mkbibindexfield{\thefield{address}}{\emph{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{Dol2}


\printindex[luoghi]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `address` is only an alias for `location`. Internally for `biblatex` `address` does not exist, it gets remapped to `location` by Biber. So everywhere except in your `.bib` file `address` must be `location`.
2. `location` (`address`) is not a normal field, it is a list field. That means you can't use `\DeclareIndexFieldFormat`, you need `\DeclareIndexListFormat`.
3. `biblatex` will only index a field if you explicitly tell it to index that field. Usually indexing happens via the bibmacros `bibindex` and `citeindex`, so you need to add `\indexlist{location}` to to those bibmacros (depending on whether you want citations and/or bibliography entries indexed; the original definition of the bibmacros can be found in `biblatex.def`: [`bibindex` is at ll. 2354-2358 [in v3.14]](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2354-L2358), [`citeindex` at ll. 2305-2309 [in v3.14]](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2305-L2309)).

You can also simplify the actual index format by using the bibmacro `index:field` (which despite its name can also be used for lists).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,indexing=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=luoghi, title=Luoghi]

\DeclareIndexListFormat{location}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:field}{\index[luoghi]}{#1}{\emph{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}%
     \indexlist{location}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}%
     \indexlist{location}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Dol2,
  address   = {Moskwa},
  author    = {Philip Döllinger},
  publisher = {Sinodal'naja tip},
  title     = {Sistematičeskoe opisanie rukopisej moskovskoj Sinodal'noj (patriaršej) biblioteki},
  year      = {1894},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Dol2}

\printindex[luoghi]
\end{document}
```

[image: Moskwa, 1]

Comment: Thank you. A question: Will the redefined bibmacros citeindex and bibindex affect in any way other indexes, such as a name index, if present?

Comment: I assume that with the ridefinition of the two macros we are just adding the "location" field to the other stuff that is already indicized (author names and titles), right?

Comment: @Teodoro The redefinitions I show will not change the *default* behaviour in any way except for also indexing the `location` (`address`) field/list. Specifically, I only added `\indexlist{location}` to the default definitions from `biblatex.def` in the appropriate place. (I edited the answer with references to the original definitions, so you can compare them yourself)